# Specify include paths individually per source file for Visual Studio C++

Tags: visual-c++, intellisense, include-path

Is it possible to specify include paths individually for each soucre *.cpp file?

Eclipse uses this method for code assistance, see [Discovery Options properties](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/reference/cdt_u_prop_build_discovery.htm)

In Visual Studio 2010, all I can see is that one can only define the include paths project-wide.

It would be nice if this individual information could then be used for the IntelliSense compiler to parse only the current active source file.

As far as I know IntelliSense parses all files at once, which I think is not appropriate for verly large projects.

Comment: VS 2012 can do it, but not 2010 or earlier.

Comment: Meanwhile I found that one can specify additional includes for say a console application. For MakefileProjects there is no such entry.